# ActiveMQ Connected consumer don't consume messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, activemq-classic

I am using NuGet to work with ActiveMQ https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/
Also tried Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.NetStd.
The situation is such that the listener successfully connects to the broker and in the web console this can be seen in the corresponding queue. But messages from the queue don't consume. Without any errors.

Something like this:
[image]

Consumer code. This is AspNet HostedService:
[image]

Connected with `tcp://...`:
[image]

Creating connection and session:
[image]

I don't get any exceptions, nothing at all. No messages are delivered to the listener. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the queuePrefetch, the asynchronous consumer does not work with the value 0, in this case, you can use only the synchronous consumer or increase the value of queuePrefetсh.
[image]